# ¿Cómo serializar un objeto que contenga otra lista de objetos en json? C#

Tags: c#, json, objeto, net, serializacion

Tengo que serializar un json, es como meter varios objetos dentro de un objeto.
Este deberia ser el resultado.

```
{
   "numeroFactura": "123",
   "nombreRazonSocial": "Vargas",
   "montoTotal": "50",
   
   "detalles": [
       {
        "codigoProducto": "aaa0001",
        "descripcion": "vasija",
        "cantidad": "5",
        "subTotal": "50"
       }
   ]
}
```

Pero al serializar solo se crea asi, sin el detalle. Use Newtonsoft y System.Text.Json de NET6 y en los 2 casos obtengo el mismo resultado.

```
{
   "numeroFactura": "123",
   "nombreRazonSocial": "Vargas",
   "montoTotal": "50",

   "detalles": []
}
```

Podria serializar por separado y despues concatenar en un solo String, pero quiero hacerlo de la manera correcta.
Se que algo me estoy saltando, pero no se que es.

El codigo que estoy usando es:

```
public class Detalle
{
    public string codigoProducto { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
    public string cantidad { get; set; }
    public string subTotal { get; set; }
}

public class Principal
{
    public string numeroFactura { get; set; }
    public string nombreRazonSocial { get; set; }
    public string montoTotal { get; set; }
    public List<Detalle> detalles { get; set; }
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Detalle detalle = new Detalle()
    {
        codigoProducto = "aaa0001",
        descripcion = "vasija",
        cantidad = "5",
        subTotal = "50"
    };

    Principal principal = new Principal()
    {
        numeroFactura = "123",
        nombreRazonSocial = "Vargas",
        montoTotal = "50",
        detalles = new List<Detalle>(),
    };

    string jsonForma1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(principal, Formatting.Indented);

    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };
    string jsonForma2 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(principal, options);
}
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal parece que la asignación del objeto es incorrecta, debería ser:

```
 Principal principal = new Principal()
 {
        numeroFactura = "123",
        nombreRazonSocial = "Vargas",
        montoTotal = "50",
        List<Detalle> detalles = new List<Detalle>
        {
        
         new Detalle
         {
            codigoProducto = "aaa0001",
            descripcion = "vasija",
            cantidad = "5",
            subTotal = "50"
         }
       }
 };
```